# Dispatcher servlet throws exception: NumberFormatException

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have Controller with `@InitBinder` that has`setAsText` method there is exception because for some unknown reason when empty string is passed. Exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

This JSP code causes error:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="organization">
        <spring:message code="label.organization"></spring:message>:</label>

    <form:select path="organization" class="form-control" id="organization">
        <form:option value="" label="- Select -" />
        <form:options items="${organizations}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" />
    </form:select>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Organization.class,
                new PropertyEditorSupport() {
                    @Override
                    public void setAsText(String text) {
                        Organization organization = organizationService.getOrganization(Integer.parseInt(text));
                        setValue(organization);
                    }
                });
    }
```

What is wrong? How to make it work?

**Update:**
I don't understand why empty string arrives as parameter to `setAsText` method. First browser makes request to url, Spring dispatcher servlet serves matching controller's method, then some magic happens where empty string arrives to `setAsText` method of @InitBinder....

Comment: Unknown reason? What do you expect `Integer.parseInt()` to do with an empty string?

Comment: The exception states that your input string was "" That cannot be parsed into an Integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

```
 public void setAsText(String text) {
        Object organization;
        if ("".equals(text)) {
            organization = (List < Organization > ) organizationService.getOrganizations();
        } else {
            organization = organizationService.getOrganization(Integer.parseInt(text));
        }

        setValue(organization);
    }
```